# Send response back to resource after request has been aborted in Twisted

Tags: python, twisted.web

I'm trying to upload file to the server. When uploading file there might be situation when I run out of free disk space and Exception is raised causing to shut down connection to client with no response sent back. I'm curious is there a way to send response to `Resource` and render it  with the result of `json` string containing status message?

Answer (score 0):

I would try surrounding your upload code with a `try...except...` block.

```
try:
  # upload file
except Exception:
  # send response to Resource
```

Comment: I'm handling `POST` requset and upload in custom `RequestFactory`. I'm not sure how to set `try...except...` block. Is it possible to tell twisted to stop reading from socket and immediately render the Resource? I tried calling `readConnectionLost` and it seems like it calls bunch of other methods in the chain causing the exception.